# Bluebird.resolve(jQuery.ajax) Warning promise rejected with non-error [object Object]

Tags: jquery, build, promise, warnings, bluebird

Problem: when passing jQuery.ajax to Promise.resolve in Bluebird.js, it throws a warning when the request fails.

Is this the correct behavior?  For some reason that I couldn't find, Bluebird does not emit this warning when it is included directly in the page.  It does emit the warning when it is bundled with Webpack.

If this is the correct behavior, what is the correct approach for using jQuery.ajax in Bluebird?  And why it does not happen when Bluebird is included directly in the page?

UPDATE: After digging a little bit, I find that it is simply a difference of the two different builds of Bluebird.  The unminified build emits warnings, but the minified build does not.  Is there a reason for this?

UPDATE 2: What causes the warning is a .finally attached to the promise.  Like so:

```
Promise
  .resolve($.getJSON('/notfound'))
  .finally(() => {})
  .catch(() => {});
```

This causes a warning:
https://jsfiddle.net/gf0jk80s/1/

This does not cause a warning:
https://jsfiddle.net/gf0jk80s/2/

As you can see the only difference is the build version used.  I would really appreciate if somebody can point me to what is wrong with my code.  Ideally, I would like it to not cause warnings for both build versions of Bluebird.  In the example, the functions are empty, but in the real code I actually do things in those two handlers.

Comment: That Bluebird warning was added in a recent version of Bluebird.  So, either you're two scenarios include different versions of Bluebird or one of them is disabling that warning.

Comment: The [Bluebird release notes for 3.0.3](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/changelog.html#3.0.3) says: "3rd party libraries rejecting promises with non-errors no longer causes warnings".  Do you have a new enough version of Bluebird to have this fix.

Comment: Both of them are 3.4.6, because I see that in the opening comments.  The one included is from /js/browser/bluebird.min.js and when it gets bundled it seems to be from /js/browser/bluebird.js.

Comment: Confirmed: it has nothing to do with the build.  The minified version of Bluebird does not emit the warning, but the normal version does emit the warning.  And it is not just this warning, other warnings as well, such as "Promise created in handler and not returned".  To test, simply include one or another.

Comment: FYI, you can disable these warnings even in the non-minified build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After digging a little bit, I find that it is simply a difference of
>   the two different builds of Bluebird. The unminified build emits
>   warnings, but the minified build does not. Is there a reason for this?

This is done because the unminified version is considered the "debug" version of the library that developers will use when writing and doing initial testing and is easier to step through with a debugger.  It is designed to be verbose with warnings to tell a developer when they might have done something wrong.

The minified version is like the "production" version of the library that is optimized for space and there's generally no point in having the production version of your app emit warnings to the user's console.

In the C/C++ world, this is analogous to a debug version of a DLL and an optimized version of a DLL.  The debug version would contain things like `ASSERT()` to inform a developer if something was not as it should be, the optimized version would not.

Comment: Thank you, this is good to know.  But now how do you differentiate which one to use when requiring it in Node?  Or building it with Webpack?  The package.json points to the full build.  I mean, my code is in development, but my use of Bluebird should always be considered production as I'm not developing it in my code.

Also, if they removed third party libraries warnings, shouldn't that also not throw warnings in the development version?

Comment: @AndréCoelho - The warnings are not for developing Bluebird code, they're to advise you when you are using promises incorrectly.  They are there to help you develop your code correctly.  I don't know why the third party jQuery promises are still causing the warning.  Typically with a build system, you'd have a means of producing a "debug" build and a "production" build and one would include the regular version and the other the minimized version.

Comment: Thanks again, that clarifies the environment options.  And yes, third party libs causing warnings is an issue as I cannot due anything about it in my code.  I guess I'll try to figure out how to always build the production version of it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndréCoelho - You can disable Bluebird warnings if you want.  See here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html

Comment: Considering that we can be fairly certain it is a bug, because of the release notes you pointed out, I think the best course is to wrap that in 'new Promise' and do the rejection manually, throwing a custom error.  I still want the warnings for valid cases and my initial idea of simply using the minified version is probably not a good idea.  But thank you very much for your help in sorting this through.